# load magento admin in iframe

Tags: magento, iframe

Trying to load my magento admin pages in an iframe.
But when I put the following code in the iframe HTML - I just get an empty window.

```
<iframe src="HTTP://ADDRESS-TO-ADMIN-PAGE" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height = "700px" width = "1000px">
</iframe>
```

Any one know why it is just displaying blank?

Thanks!

Comment: "the following code" -> post it!

Comment: Hi Kevin - the iframe code is posted in the original post, but here it is again :  <iframe src="HTTP://ADDRESS-TO-ADMIN-PAGE" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height = "700px" width = "1000px">
</iframe>

Comment: I guess no one knows? :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set

System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > **Allow Magento Backend to run in frame** 
from it's default "**Only from same domain**" to "**Enabled**"!